# "Are fees paid current?" meaning

Tags: meaning

This is an extract from a [form](https://www.pnc.com/content/dam/pnc-home-hq/pdfs/Loan%20Mod%20Application%20FINAL%208-21-15.pdf) applying for mortgage relief from PNC (PDF, 3.9MB):

[image: Form]

Section 2C of this application asks about condominium or homeowner association fees. It says "Are fees paid current?"

What does it mean? Does it mean that whether I paid the fees up-to-date? Is it asking for the previous late payment or no? How does the word "current" translate here? Or is "paid current" one word?

Comment: It appears to be asking whether you're up-to-date in paying your association fees.  Very poorly worded.

Comment: What @Hot Licks said. It should probably have been *Are fees paid **currently**?* (or even more idiomatically, *Are fees **currently paid**?*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think "Are fees paid currently?" is slightly odd.  *Currently* means now, but the verb is in the past tense.  It sounds like "Are fees being paid currently?" but that's not likely what they want to know, since you can resume paying fees after leaving some unpaid.  What they're likely asking is "Is your HOA account **current**?" which means "Do you owe any fees?"  They ask the applicant to attach an HOA statement, so that's a clue.

Comment: @deadrat: I really don't know what meaning is intended in OP's specific context, but I'd have to say that (in BrE, at least) I've never heard anything like *Is your credit card account current?* used to mean *Do you owe anything on your credit card?*

Comment: Looked up many sites and even called the bank. The conclusion is what you all said: is your account balance in good standing? I think they want to know if the applicant owe anything or has any obligation to the HOA in this case. From "fees are current" in finance I guess... Thank you all for your help!

Comment: @FumbleFingers It never occurred to me that this might be an Americanism.  I guess my parochialism is showing.  The google reports many hits for "Is your account current?" from credit card companies to cable TV providers to universities and so on.

Comment: @deadrat: My understanding of *Is your account current?* would be that I'm being asked if I've allowed my account (whatever that represents) to ***lapse***. Just as *Is your insurance current?* isn't asking whether I owe the insurance company any money - it just asks whether I have a *currently active* insurance policy. If AmE uses the term differently I suppose my closevote might have been a bit hasty.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A construction loan company in California follows up "Is your account current?" with "If NO, when will you send out your past due payment?"  Which is what I'm used to.  If a company wants to know whether I'm still conducting business with them, they ask "Is your account active?"

Answer (score 2):

"Fees paid" should be read as one phrase.  Are fees paid current? means is the account up to date.